# How to set focus back to textbox after an error message.?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form with several textboxes and need to validate data upon clicking the last command button on the form. The code is:

```
Private Sub CmdSave1_Click()

 Dim row As Long
  Dim c As Range
 row = ActiveCell.row


  For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
     If c.Value = txt_BPName1 Then
        MsgBox " Duplicate Found.Please enter unique Base Product"
        txt_BPName1.SetFocus  '>>> the cursor does not return textbox here.
              'txt_SPName1.SetFocus
                End If
                Next
                'txt_SPName1.SetFocus
                'Exit Sub
     For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
         If c.Value = txt_SPName1 Then
           MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " Duplicate sub Product Found."
              txt_SPName1.SetFocus
              End If
              Next
              'txt_loc1.SetFocus
              'Exit Sub
```

Exit sub will put the cursor back into the textbox. But, I have other lines of code that need to happen below exit sub line. So, I do not want to exit sub. Is there a substitute for exit sub? Or can I break out and enter the sub back again?

Comment: That is not VB.NET, it is not VBA, it is not vbScript and it is not a macro; so all those tags are irrelevant.  It is VB6 code

Comment: For what it's worth, "Exit Sub" doesn't put the cursor in the textbox, "txt_SPName1.SetFocus" puts the curson in the textbox.  "Exit Sub" stops running the code.  By the way, this code would be a lot clearer and efficient if you used the find function instead of looping through each record to see if a duplicate was already in there.  I'll leave it to you to research and implement.

Comment: @Plutonix I think it is VBA, but you're correct, most of the tags are irrelevant.

Comment: With this code you wouldn't ever be able to tell if it did or not, once you hit the error you have a msgbox, then set focus, then go to the next item, then continue on.  You need to put an Exit sub when you hit an error or it will just process the entire form anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "GoTo" statement:

```
For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
      If c.Value = txt_BPName1 Then
         MsgBox " Duplicate Found.Please enter unique Base Product"
         txt_BPName1.SetFocus  '>>> the cursor does not return textbox here.
         'txt_SPName1.SetFocus
      GoTo DuplicateFound
      End If
 Next

 ....rest of code

 DuplicateFound:
      ....code you want to happen if a duplicate is found.
```